# Confidence intervals for repeatability

Tags: confidence-interval, repeated-measures, repeatability

I have calculated the repeatability of individuals' responses to a stimulus using the methodology of [Lessells & Boag (1987) Auk 104:116](http://www.univet.hu/users/jkis/education/Kutatastervezes/Lessells_Boag_Auk_87_Unrepeatable_repeatabilities_-_a_common_mistake.pdf), where repeatability r = among-groups variance component / (among-groups variance component + within-groups variance component).

How do I assign confidence intervals to my estimate of r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for bootstrap to compute 95% CIs. This is what is generally done with coefficient of heritability or intraclass correlation. (I found no other indication in Falconer's book.) There is an example in the [gap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gap/index.html) package of an handmade bootstrap (see `help(h2)`) in case of the correlation-based heritability coefficient, $h^2$. IMO, you're better off computing the variance components yourself, and using the [boot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html) package. Briefly, the idea is to write a small function that returns your MSs ratio and then call the `boot()` function, e.g.

```
library(boot)
repeat.boot <- function(data, x) { foo(data[x,])$ratio }
res.boot <- boot(yourdata, repeat.boot, 500)
boot.ci(res.boot, type="bca")
```

where `foo(x)` is a function that take a data.frame, compute the variance ratio, and return it as `ratio`.

**Sidenote:** I just checked on http://rseek.org and found this project, [rptR: Repeatability estimation for Gaussian and non-Gaussian data](http://rptr.r-forge.r-project.org/). I don't know if the above is not simpler.